# I need to mount directory from one hdd to public_html folder

Tags: apache-2.2, filesystems, mount, hard-drive, centos6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hard drive on server which hosts public_html folder is full. What to do?](https://serverfault.com/questions/412731/hard-drive-on-server-which-hosts-public-html-folder-is-full-what-to-do)

i have a hard drive (1TB) which has a folder named "flvideo2" i need to mount into /home/ivan/public_html/flvideo2/ because my home folder is almost full.
my home folder is on different hard-drive (2tb,full)...

Is this possible, and how can i do it?

The server is running on 64 bit centos6/apache2/php5.

Answer (score 2):

mount --bind /some/folder/where/original/is /home/user/videos

**man mount**

```
 -B, --bind
     Remount a subtree somewhere else (so that its contents are available 
     in both places). See above.
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is NOT a copy of the folder and if you rm the folder instead of unmounting it, the folder will be gone from the harddrive.

Comment: Thanks! will this last even after server reboot?

Comment: no. but you can put it in /etc/fstab like this: /mnt/media/media    /media      none        bind        0 0

Comment: why none? should it not be ext3?

Comment: you are making a "virtual copy" from one folder to another folder. ext3 is involved when you take a /dev/block-device (sda1,hde4,etc) to a folder. --bind does not mount anything, it only makes some folder visible in another place.